# How do you stop MySQL replication using mysql shell 8.0.23?

Tags: mysql, backup

I am using MySQL 8.0.23 docker container to back up an instance using `util.dump_instance()` from a time delayed replica instance using MySQL shell in Python mode.

How can I stop the replication before I run the instance dump?
I could find no examples in the documentation.

I would run the equivalent of the following statement:

```
mysql -h"$MYSQL_HOST" -P"$MYSQL_PORT" -u$MYSQL_USER -p"$MYSQL_PASS" -e 'STOP SLAVE SQL_THREAD;'
```

so starting the replication would be easier on the instance since the binary log will contain the entries to be replicated.

Current code:

```
import os 
import time

TIME = time.strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M")

MYSQL_HOST = os.getenv('MYSQL_HOST')
MYSQL_PORT = os.getenv('MYSQL_PORT')

BACKUP_PATH = "/backup/"+MYSQL_HOST+":"+MYSQL_PORT+"//"+TIME

util.dump_instance( BACKUP_PATH, {'dryRun': False, 'threads': 4, 'showProgress': True, 'consistent': True})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **mysqladmin** to start/stop the replication like this:

```
# mysqladmin  -u root -p start-slave
# mysqladmin  -u root -p stop-slave
```

Comment: will it work from the mysql shell in python mode?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appears that the answer is not in the code but in the understanding of how the dump instance utility works. There is no need to stop the replication before using it because it allows transactions to finish running before acquiring a global read lock on the tables of the instance.